Adding a new sink in a garage to existing plumbing
I would like to add a new garage sink. The wall I am working on backs on to a bathroom with an existing sink. I can tap into the existing bathroom sink H&C water supply in the drywall. Can I also tap into the existing 1.5 inch PVC sink drain in the drywall (which runs horizontally draining to the main vent pipe a few feet away) by adding a T piece? I will definitely install a P trap under the new sink. Would this be the correct approach and code compliant?

The correct approach, but code compliant might be different.  Two separate sinks on the same sink drain line.  I and you know that you will not be using the sinks together/at same time, but not sure if code sees it it the same.  Run it by your local building department to be sure about code compliant(or not).

Is the garage insulated and HVAC'ed?

What you need to use is a combo wye.
It can be a little tricky cutting out a piece of the drain and slipping in the wye, but usually it can be done.  Remember to use primer and the correct glue.
